# html element is not taking the height of the browser even with height 100%

Tags: html, css

when I inspect my html element I find out that it is not taking 100 % of the browser view even if I am setting height to 100% in my css sheet.I test it with chrome and firefox and it is the same.The browser adds display:block to my html element could it be the reason?

Comment: Make a fiddle please :)

Comment: 1) What is the height you do get, and what is the height of the viewport? 2) Are you sure the css stylesheet gets applied at all; test by giving it a background color or something. 3) Yes, html has display:block by default; what display value did you expect?

Comment: @desmanda did you find a fix to your problem?

Comment: hey thanks for ur answers I just added to body min-height=100% and it works finally ;)

Answer (score 3):

> it is not taking 100 % of the browser view

If you strictly want the element to take the height of the 'browser view', or *viewport* as it's called, simply do:

```
#element {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

That sets the element to 100% the height of the viewport. Check [this page](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) for browser support info.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide a code/example but my guess is that your `html` and `body` don't have the `height: 100%` as well. Try to add them to your css

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
}
```

Note that the height percentage refers to the element's parent, so if the element's parent is only 30% of the page for example, your element will be 30% too.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your HTML and Body are 100%;

```css
body, html {
    height: 100%
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason I have found this happens is because you forgot to set `height: 100%` for **both** `html` and `body` elements.

Remember **percentage** is a relative unit and it can't work until it finds a parent that has declared absolute height/width. Also, if the parent has height/width set in percentage, that calculated value will be used as the basis for computing the percentage for children.

Also, while doing this, you might want to consider thinking about the `box-sizing` because if you set height as `100%` and then apply margins and paddings to that element, it's gonna occupy more than 100% of it's parent's height.

Assuming your markup is like...

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="my-element"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### If you still wanna use percentage as length value, do.

```
html,
body, 
.my-element {
    height: 100%;
}
```

#### Or use the better length unit `vh`;

```
.my-element {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Read up more about `vh` here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length

Check browser compatibility here. - http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units